# Hudson: setting up classpath

Tags: junit, classpath, hudson

Please what is the way to set classpath in Hudson. I have set of xml and properties files in a C:\CQ_HOME\config folder. These files are referred by the application during server start-up. But when I use Hudson to run JUnit test cases, they fail because xml and properties files are not found and I get FileNotFoundException. Is there a way to add above directory in classpath of Hudson.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Under hudson\configure you have Global properties you can add  Environment variables

Comment: i did that but still Hudson is not able to pick config files.